# Unable to add device in Member Center

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-developer-program, udid

I am trying to add device (UDID) in iOS developer account. I followed all steps to add device, but I am getting a screen with only a "Loading..." with activity indicator on Register button.

I have waited 20-30 minutes but nothing happen other than activity indicator endlessly spinning. Please help me in that.

[image: Developer Center]

Comment: Some times the  device is added although it hangs in the loading... Have you tried refreshing the page and checking if the device was added to the list?

Comment: @nunofmendes Yes I tried this way even I logout and again loggedIn but not success. :(

Comment: Try in Safari (or in Chrome if you are using Safari). Try cleaning cookies and cache. Some times there is a piece of data hanging in the insides of your browser. Also check if the UDID is actually real, although apple does not seem to check it, and therefore allows invalid device ids.

Comment: yeah sure, I have chrome, I will try. Hope so this time I will get success :)

Comment: yeahhh... This trick is helpful for me. This time I tried in chrome.  Thank you

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will just add here the comment that answered/helped this user.

--

- Some times the device is added although it hangs in the loading... Check if the device was added to the list.
- Try in Safari (or in Chrome if you are using Safari).
- Try cleaning cookies and cache. Some times there is a piece of data hanging in the insides of your browser.
- Also check if the UDID is actually real, although apple does not seem to check it, and therefore allows invalid device ids.

Comment: Switching to Safari worked for me! Thanks. Why is so hard to build a better member center Apple? -_-